# Can I access dynamically-allocated memory if I've "lost" the last remaining pointer to it?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

Code as follows:

```
char *p=malloc(200);
p=NULL;
```

Now that I've NULLed `p`, is there any way in which I can use those 200 bytes of memory again? If not, can I at least free them?

Comment: No you can't, so don't lose it.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I bang my head against the wall. How can I stop it from hurting?"

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Attach a pillow to the wall.

Comment: @stefan Then I wouldn't be hitting the wall

Comment: I would love to know why you would want to do that.

Comment: @AshRj Ok, so no pillow for you then.

Answer (score 3):

before calling `p=NULL;`
use `free(p);`

but before freeing the memory if u assign the pointer to NULL it will become lost...

Comment: This does not regain the memory, that prevents it being leaked in the first place. Not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot you donated it to Mr. No-one one when you did,

```
p = NULL;
```

And since Mr. No-one is selfish he will not return you anything given to him. He will only give it back to your OS when your program ends and the process in which your application runs exits.

Comment: `He will only give it back to your OS when your program ends and the process in which your application runs exits.` Speaking strictly, in the context of the [tag:c++] tag, this is _not_ a given.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In context of most(*read all*) it is a given.

Comment: Abstraction is healthy.

Answer (score 2):

You always need a pointer to hold the memory position otherwise you can't get it back.

```
char *p=malloc(200);
char *p2 = p;
p = NULL;
free(p2);
```

Comment: Pointers do not "hold" 200 byte memory blocks.

Comment: fine, they hold a handle for that 200 byte memory block

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, there is no way to get that memory back. You could prevent losing it, but not get it back. The only option is to exit the program.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you use a garbage collector, such as the [Boehm-Demers-Weiser collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).  If you cannot use a garbage collector, then the memory cannot be reclaimed.

Of course, the memory is reclaimed if you call `free(p)` before setting `p = NULL`, but you knew that already.

And furthermore, the memory will be reclaimed automatically by the operating system if you `exec()` or if the process exits.

Comment: `the memory is reclaimed if you call free(p) before setting p = NULL, but you knew that already.` Are you sure?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I choose to be sure.

Comment: That's your prerogative, I suppose.